# Time interval class that enhances constructor argument handling of its parent class

Tags: python, datetime, inheritance, interval, constructor

I am making a subclass of a well-established python class:  [`pendulum.Period`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#period), which overrides both `__new__` and `__init__` (it does this because *it* is subclassing the python builtin class `timedelta`, which uses `__new__`).

In my case, I want my class to handle a wider range of arguments than the superclass.  The only way I have managed to get the code to work is to *duplicate* my handling code in both `__new__` and `__init__` -- this is because, per the documentation, the arguments passed to `__new__` are then passed to the `__init__` of the new instance, unaltered.

The result is repeated code execution. Is this avoidable?

```
from pendulum import Period, Date

def _toDate(val):
    """
    Convert various inputs into a Date
    """
    if isinstance(val, int) or isinstance(val, float):
        return Date.fromtimestamp(val)
    elif isinstance(val, tuple):
        return Date(*val)
    return Date(val.year, val.month, val.day)


class MyInterval(Period):    
    def __new__(cls, start, end, inclusive=True, **kwargs):
        start = _toDate(start)
        end = _toDate(end)

        if inclusive:
            end = end.add(days=1)

        return super(MyInterval, cls).__new__(cls, start, end, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, start, end, inclusive=True, **kwargs):
        """
        Creates a pendulum Period where the interval is limited to whole 
        days. Both are cast to dates, then the end date is incremented by 
        one day if inclusive=True
        :param start: cast to date
        :param end: cast to date
        :param inclusive: [True] whether the last day of the interval should
          be included (increments by 1 day)
        """
        start = _toDate(start)
        end = _toDate(end)

        if inclusive:
            end = end.add(days=1)

        super(MyInterval, self).__init__(start, end, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why do you need `__init__` if you have `__new__`?

Comment: @StephenRauch it's just because the superclass specifies both `__init__` and `__new__`. I depend on the superclass's code working in both steps, so I need to give it valid inputs to both those functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t expect to be further subclassing `MyInterval`, you could just use a helper method for construction.

```
class MyInterval(Period):

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, start, end, inclusive=True, **kwargs):
        start = _toDate(start)
        end = _toDate(end)

        if inclusive:
            end = end.add(days=1)

        return cls(start, end, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you could use a helper method to avoid the duplicated code (but not duplicated execution).

```
class MyInterval(Period):

    @staticmethod
    def _fixup(start, end, inclusive):
        start = _toDate(start)
        end = _toDate(end)

        if inclusive:
            end = end.add(days=1)

        return start, end

    def __new__(cls, start, end, inclusive=True, **kwargs):
        start, end = cls._fixup(start, end, inclusive)
        return super().__new__(start, end, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, start, end, inclusive=True, **kwargs):
        start, end = self._fixup(start, end, inclusive)
        return super().__init__(start, end, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I like the classmethod approach. The downside is obviously that it doesn't stop anyone from using the ordinary constructor-  which may lead to unexpected results if the body code depends on the proper input processing at construction (though it doesn't really in this case)